# Scrapy - running spider from a python script

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to run scrapy from a `python` script according to documentation http://scrapy.readthedocs.io/en/0.16/topics/practices.html

```
def CrawlTest():

    spider = PitchforkSpider(domain='"pitchfork.com"')
    crawler = Crawler(Settings())
    crawler.configure()
    crawler.crawl(spider)
    crawler.start()
    log.start()
    reactor.run() # the script will block here
```

but when I run it, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'update_settings'
```

has something been deprecated? what is wrong here?

my version is `Scrapy 1.1.2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at Scrapy 0.16 docs but using Scrapy 1.1.2.

Here is the [correct documentation page](http://scrapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script).

FYI, you should now be using `CrawlerProcess` or `CrawlerRunner`.